# iOS - Editing text in UITextView changes attributes

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview, nsattributedstring

I am using **UITextView** to display attributed string data. Everything is working fine but if i edit **UITextView** in a way like:

**Scenario 1:** I have two lines first line is with normal font and second line is with bold font if i edit the second line all of the text is converted to Bold.

**Scenario 2:** If i move the cursor to first line with normal font and remove or add a character all of the bold font is gone.

**Scenario 3:** If i have a third line with underline font changing it changes all of the text to be underline.

I am using **setAllowsEditingTextAttributes** as **True** for my UITextView

Why is this happening? How can i prevent this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use UITextView delegate to set the attribute:

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text{
    //Here you set the attribute of your text
}
```

Comment: I was making the mistake of assigning textView.text inside this method removing it resolved my problem. Thanks